Incorrect row drawing in DataTable PrimeVue?
After adding :virtualScrollerOptions="{ itemSize: 10 }", incorrect row rendering occurs. When you click on the bottom arrow of the scroll bar in https://stackblitz.com/edit/wag9bxpi?file=src%2FApp.vue, you see rows 1-11 (from the top) and then 31 and so on.
Is there any way to prevent this behavior?
Changing itemSize only shifts the problem, and scrollHeight too :-(
